# Are drone camera platforms on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Are serious camera drone platforms like [GoPro Karma](https://shop.gopro.com/karma) considered on topic here?

Answer (score 4):

Probably depends on if you are doing video or photos.  I'd expect it to be on topic for still images.  Video would be on topic for video production Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Besides whether or not you're talking about photo vs. video, if the question is centered more on the drone itself (motor power, blade types, battery runtime, drone laws, etc.), it would be off-topic.

Comment: I can see that...   I wonder if the SE AJ Henderson mentioned feels the same way.  I'm not on that SE and was hoping to break the 200rep barrier before joining any more.

Comment: AJ is a mod over at [video.se] as well. He'll have a good idea of the pulse at both sites.

Comment: Looks like you got your 200 rep. You're welcome. ;-)

Comment: thank you *blinks*